# How to decrease the space between the items in a Bootstrap navbar without changing the padding in .nav >li > a in bootstrap.css directly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following home.html file and an external css file named "navbar.css" which I am loading after the "bootstrap.min.css". I am trying to get the work done by assigning a class named "custom-menu-item" to the appropriate  elements and changing the padding in "navbar.css"(but no change to padding is taking place)

```css
    .custom-menu-item{
      padding:10px 13px;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/custom/navbar.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid custom-coontainer-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header ">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="custom-menu-item">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle custom-menu-item" data-toggle="dropdown" id="about-us-menu" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About  Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="about-us-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
    
            <li class="dropdown ">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle custom-menu-item" data-toggle="dropdown" id="admin-info-menu" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration  <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="admin-info-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
    
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can add your own css file (**after** bootstrap's) and write `.nav >li > a {padding: whatever}` to override bootstrap defaults

Comment: @fen1x First of all thanks for your kind reply.But I just want to do it ,not by the method you mentioned, but by assigning a class named "custom-menu-item" (please see code above) to the corresponding <a> tags pointed to by ".nav >li >a"  and changing the padding in an external css file "navbar.css". But it is not working.Can you please tell me why(I am trying to do it just for practice.Not good at CSS at all).Another thing is that if I try to do something else like changing background color etc. it works(only changing padding values does not works).

Comment: Selector `.nav>li>a` is more _specific_ than `.custom-menu-item` (read about specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)). Because of specificity you can either use `!important` with your custom class (not a good practice), or use more specific selector than bootstrap one.

Comment: @fen1x thank you for the link to specificity.Actually I never have learned about specificity before, so did not know much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your own style after boostrap css files:

```
.nav > li > a {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style> 
      .nav > li > a {
        padding: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid custom-coontainer-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header ">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my-navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="custom-menu-item">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle custom-menu-item" data-toggle="dropdown" id="about-us-menu" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About  Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="about-us-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
    
            <li class="dropdown ">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle custom-menu-item" data-toggle="dropdown" id="admin-info-menu" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration  <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="admin-info-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
    
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/gsv9po8f/3/

```css
.custom-menu-item{
  padding: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <h1>Site Name</h1>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button class=" btn btn-primary navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
      <span class="sr-only">Open Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#" class="custom-menu-item">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle custom-menu-item" data-toggle="dropdown" id="about-us-menu" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About  Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="about-us-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
    
            <li class="dropdown ">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle custom-menu-item" data-toggle="dropdown" id="admin-info-menu" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration  <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="admin-info-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```